# How to make polylines using google maps api and flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I have been working with google maps api and flutter and cannot see polyline between 2 markers.Does anyone have any idea how to create a polyline between user entered location?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the implementation of polylines in the plugin example
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/place_polyline.dart

Comment: Thanx i will surely look into it